# Tensorflow Argmax: What's the difference between "axis" and "dimension" parameter?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, argmax

The current version of Tensorflow Argmax doesn't specify what's the difference between the "axis" and "dimension" arguments. Here is the only information given in the [official manual](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard8/tf.argmax.md):

```
tf.argmax(input, axis=None, name=None, dimension=None) {#argmax}

Returns the index with the largest value across axes of a tensor.

Args:

input: A Tensor. Must be one of the following types: float32, float64, int64, int32, uint8, uint16, int16, int8, complex64, complex128, qint8, quint8, qint32, half.

axis: A Tensor. Must be one of the following types: int32, int64. int32, 0 <= axis < rank(input). Describes which axis of the input Tensor to reduce across. For vectors, use axis = 0.

name: A name for the operation (optional).

Returns:

A Tensor of type int64.
```

Can someone clarify? Which one is actually the dimension being reduced?

Comment: Since `dimension` is not documented it means it's not part of API (ie, probably an old keyword arg that was left over from refactoring/renaming, do not use)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TensorFlow is transitioning to use `axis` rather than `dimension` which is going to be deprecated soon: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear. The documentation is definitely not very complete. :)